# How to determine if characters in an Oracle DB field are within the UTF8 charset but outside of LATN-1 with SQL?

Tags: oracle, utf-8, data-conversion, latin1

I currently have the need to write a SQL query to determine the number of rows in my UTF8 Oracle database that are not compatible with another system that uses LATIN-1.

For example, `Über` should not return a result, but `翻译` should

I have tried queries such as:

```
select decode(convert(convert('Über test', 'WE8ISO8859P1'), 'UTF8'), convert('Über test', 'UTF8'), 1, 0) from dual;
```

However, this does not give me the result that I need. Can anyone provide a SQL-only solution to this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have figured it out:

`select * from (select asciistr(convert('test string goes here', 'UTF8')) as str from dual) where regexp_like(str, '.*\\([1-9A-F]|0[1-9A-F]).*');`

Using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement_%28Unicode_block%29 as a reference, the LATIN-1 block of unicode ends at \00FF.

For example,

```
SQL> select * from (select asciistr(convert('翻译', 'UTF8')) as str from dual) where regexp_like(str, '.*\\([1-9A-F]|0[1-9A-F]).*');

STR
------------------------------
\7FFB\8BD1
```

If someone could double-check this from a logical standpoint, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't bother to mention an Oracle version.  Up to 11.2, you should use the Oracle provided character set scanner (CSSCAN) for this purpose.  Starting with 12.1, there's  new utility called Oracle Database Migration Assistant for Unicode.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will look into those - unfortunately I cannot run any utilities on this database. I have to execute via a standard SQL query.